# Python - draw gradient into selected irregular area of image

Tags: python, image, graphics

I was thrown into graphics and Python in my new project, but I'm completely green and I need some help/guidance what to do. Here is my problem:

I need to create the graphics for screen, which will be presenting the distance of boat from the nearest objects, like a parking assistant. Depending on a measurement from the sensor (ranges of values), different areas of irregular shapes should be filled with gradient (close to boat red, far from boat green), with the direction according to arrow. There will be many sensors working independently, all the program will be finally on Raspberry PI.

How to select individual irregular areas and fill it with gradient? Or maybe I should use layers to put image of gradient from GIMP on a image of boat? Where should I start looking?

Up to this moment I tried to use cv2 library. And I found a lead here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-create-different-shapes-using-canvas-class/?ref=rp

Screen:
[Boat parking assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkvTW.png)

[Whole view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jbv2.jpg)

I was searching a lot and I couldn't any answers that will get me closer to solution. I will aprreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You could also use **OpenCV** and its `ellipse()` method something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cv2

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('radar.png')

# Define some parameters common to all calls
centre = (460,480)
angle  = 180
start, end = 25, 80
thickness = 60

# Draw those crazy arcs
cv2.ellipse(im, center=centre, axes=(180,180), angle=angle, startAngle=start, endAngle=end, color=(0,0,255),thickness=thickness)
cv2.ellipse(im, center=centre, axes=(240,240), angle=angle, startAngle=start, endAngle=end, color=(0,50,205),thickness=thickness)
cv2.ellipse(im, center=centre, axes=(300,300), angle=angle, startAngle=start, endAngle=end, color=(0,100,155),thickness=thickness)
cv2.ellipse(im, center=centre, axes=(360,360), angle=angle, startAngle=start, endAngle=end, color=(0,150,105),thickness=thickness)
cv2.ellipse(im, center=centre, axes=(420,420), angle=angle, startAngle=start, endAngle=end, color=(0,200,55),thickness=thickness)
cv2.ellipse(im, center=centre, axes=(480,480), angle=angle, startAngle=start, endAngle=end, color=(0,255,0),thickness=thickness)

# Save
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

[image]

---

You can simplify the above code by building a partially completed function call filled out with all the invariant parts of the function, then just set whatever is different for each specific invocation. The result is identical but the code is arguably neater:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
from functools import partial

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('radar.png')

# Define a partially filled in parameter list of invariant parts to make life easier
arc = partial(cv2.ellipse,
              center = (460,480),
              angle = 180,
              startAngle = 25,
              endAngle = 80,
              thickness = 60)

# Draw those crazy arcs by filling in the variable parts
arc(im, axes=(180,180), color=(0,0,255))
arc(im, axes=(240,240), color=(0,50,205))
arc(im, axes=(300,300), color=(0,100,155))
arc(im, axes=(360,360), color=(0,150,105))
arc(im, axes=(420,420), color=(0,200,55))
arc(im, axes=(480,480), color=(0,255,0))

# Save
cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

**Earlier Answer**

I would (somewhat more carefully than illustrated) create a greyscale PNG file with each of the zones set to a different number like this:

[image]

The two (reddest in the colour images above) zones nearest the boat are set to 10 and 11 - they are darkest grey. The next two zones further away are set to 20 and 21. The next two furthest away from boat are 30 and 31. The two zones (green in your colour diagram) are set to 60 and 61.

You can now generate any zone turned on with a simple line of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load label image as greyscale
label = cv2.imread('labels.png',0)

# Make empty 4-channel RGBA image same size
RGBA = np.zeros((h,w,4), dtype=np.uint8)

# Zone 10 on
zone10 = RGBA.copy()
zone10[label==10] = [0,0,255,255]  # Anywhere label=10, image is red and opaque
cv2.imwrite('zone10.png', zone10)  # Save to disk so you can see it

# Zone 11 on
zone11 = RGBA.copy()
zone11[label==11] = [0,0,255,255]  # Anywhere label=11, image is red and opaque
cv2.imwrite('zone11.png', zone11)  # Save to disk so you can see it

# Zone 20 on
zone20 = RGBA.copy()
zone20[label==20] = [0,50,200,255] # Anywhere label=20, image is orangey-red and opaque
cv2.imwrite('zone20.png', zone20)  # Save to disk so you can see it

# Zone 21 on
zone21 = RGBA.copy()
zone21[label==21] = [0,50,200,255] # Anywhere label=21, image is orangey-red and opaque
cv2.imwrite('zone21.png', zone21)  # Save to disk so you can see it

# Zone 30 on
zone30 = RGBA.copy()
zone30[label==30] = [0,100,150,255]# Anywhere label=30, image is orangey-red and opaque
cv2.imwrite('zone30.png', zone30)  # Save to disk so you can see it

# Zone 31 on
zone31 = RGBA.copy()
zone31[label==31] = [0,100,150,255]# Anywhere label=31, image is orangey-red and opaque
cv2.imwrite('zone31.png', zone31)  # Save to disk so you can see it

# Zones 10, 11, 20, 21, 30 on
combined = np.maximum.reduce([zone10, zone11, zone20, zone21, zone30])
cv2.imwrite('combined.png',combined)
```

Here is an animation of the resulting images, composited over some waves with parts of the boat composited over the waves first:

[image]

So you can adapt this image to whatever your sensors are telling you, then paste this image over your background with the transparency layer determining which segments are visible.

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, parking, boat, parking sensor, bumper zone, radar, green, red, OpenCV, ellipse, arc, partial function, partially complete.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Unfortunately, I can't draw ellipse or arc to fill these areas, because all the areas are not identical :( I have just added the whole screen.

I will choose this path with setting alpha channels. As I understand I should create one PNG file with all zones coloured with RGB values. I don't understand how I can assign every zone to be shown independently. I'm not sure, but I thought that alpha channel is related to whole picture, not only to part of it...

Sorry for my newbie questions :)

Comment: Ok, I had another attempt and it should be much better now. Please have another look.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I'm closer to the solution :) but I have a main question - how did you define in labels.png which zone is 10,11 etc.?

What I understand:
1. I create one .png with all zones in gray colours
2. Somehow I define which zone is which label
3. I upload image as grayscale
4. Then I define each label's color and save it to use later depending on sensor's value. Then in other 'animation' program I upload saved .png files. Is that right?

I have also another question - does it work in the same way when I colour the zones with gradient (recommendation from above)?

Comment: 1) Correct. 2) It's arbitrary, you can define any zone with any number - number them however you like. 3) Correct. 4) Not sure what you mean. Using your sensor data, you have to decide which zones to turn on. I have just showed how to turn on any zone and how to combine them. So you need to do that according to your sensors. I hope that helps.

Comment: The initial image with the zones is just labelling what is what and doesn't define any colours, so I made it greyscale because that's smaller to store and still allows 256 different zones to be specified, and could even label 65,536 zones if we made it 16-bit. Colour was unnecessary, that was all.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!!! :) But why np.maximum.reduce() gives me two combined zones, but with black background?

I created the new question about this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139701/python-cv2-numpy-combining-two-images